# For any $x>0$, does $|a-b| < x$ imply that $|a-b|=0$?

Tags: definition

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. For any $x > 0$:
$$
|a-b| < x
$$
implies that:
$$
a=b
$$

Is this statement true? Why?

### My attempt:

I think it is true. My reasoning is that, if $x$ is allowed to be anything larger than $0$, but not $0$, it will contain an infinitesimal that is closest possible to $0$, but not exactly $0$. I know such thing doesn't exist in the set of real numbers, but this is my intuition.

Then, if we say that there are numbers $a$ and $b$, such that their absolute difference $|a-b|$ is even smaller than $x$, then what possibilities do we have? We already said that $x$ could be the smallest positive number that is not $0$, so if $|a-b| < x$ is true, then $|a-b|$ is even smaller than the smallest positive number $x$.

If a number, e.g. $|a-b|$ (non-negative) is smaller than the smallest positive number, then it must be that $|a-b| = 0$. I cannot find any other possibility.

Comment: Prove it by contradiction.  If $b \neq a$ then there is a positive distance between them.  Let $x$ be less than this.

Comment: Are you implying that the statement is true? Thank you.

Comment: Well, yeah.  My argument is essentially the same as the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

If $|a-b|> 0$, then $$|a-b|<|a-b|$$

Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: Could you please also answer the 1st part: is the statement true? (I will think about the rest of your post and give an answer; thank you)

Comment: yes, it is true. The working should give you a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here: If it were $|a-b|\leq x$ instead of $<$, the conclusion still holds, simply choose (assume by the contrary) $x=\dfrac{1}{2}|a-b|$.

Answer (score 0):

If possible let $a \neq b$
$$\Rightarrow |a-b|>0$$
$\Rightarrow$ for any $x \in (0, |a-b|) $  clearly $|a-b|>x>0$    and  this is a contradiction to the given condition.
$$ $$ $\therefore$ our assumption is wrong and $a=b$